# Reorder row columns in repeating CSS grid/table

Tags: html, css, css-tables, css-grid

When displaying multiple items in a table/grid like-manner, is it possible for the CSS to override the elements order, without knowing the number of "rows" in advance?

e.g. here is a standard table, and a more compact alternative for the same data.  But I had to move some HTML elements for the 2nd one (1, 4, 2, 3), otherwise the 4th column got offset a row.

```css
.layout1 {
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto max-content;
  grid-row-gap: 0.2em;
}
.layout2 {
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto max-content;
}
.layout2 .col1 {
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.layout2 .col4 {
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.layout2-5 .col2 {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.layout2-5 .col3 {
  grid-column: 2;
}
.layout2-5 .col4 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 { padding: 0 1em; }
.col1 { background: #F99; }
.col2 { background: #9F9; }
.col3 { background: #99F; }
.col4 { background: #9FF; }
```

```html
<div class="layout1">
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div><div class="col2">2</div><div class="col3">3</div><div class="col4">4</div>
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div><div class="col2">2</div><div class="col3">3</div><div class="col4">4</div>
  <div class="col1">1</div><div class="col2">2</div><div class="col3">3</div><div class="col4">4</div>
</div>
<div class="layout2">
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div><div class="col4">4</div><div class="col2">2</div><div class="col3">3</div>
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div><div class="col4">4</div><div class="col2">2</div><div class="col3">3</div>
  <div class="col1">1</div><div class="col4">4</div><div class="col2">2</div><div class="col3">3</div>
</div>
 <div class="layout2 layout2-5">
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div><div class="col2">2</div><div class="col3">3</div><div class="col4">4</div>
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div><div class="col2">2</div><div class="col3">3</div><div class="col4">4</div>
  <div class="col1">1</div><div class="col2">2</div><div class="col3">3</div><div class="col4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As i know, you can reorder rows in CSS only if you are using **Flexbox**

Comment: If I can do this with `flex`, or normal `table` or whatever that is fine. But if you are referring to the `order` property, that applies to grids as well, but how would you apply it to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `grid-auto-flow: dense`, allowing for previous cells to get filled in, with a fully repeatable layout as long as the data item does fill all cells.

```css
.layout2 {
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.layout2 .col1 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.layout2 .col2 {
  grid-column: 1;
}
.layout2 .col3 {
  grid-column: 2;
}
.layout2 .col4 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: span 2;
  height: 2.5em;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 { padding: 0 1em; }
.col1 { background: #F99; }
.col2 { background: #9F9; }
.col3 { background: #99F; }
.col4 { background: #9FF; }
```

```html
<div class="layout2">
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div>
  <div class="col2">2</div>
  <div class="col3">3</div>
  <div class="col4">4</div>

  <div class="col1">1</div>
  <div class="col2">2</div>
  <div class="col3">3</div>
  <div class="col4">4</div>
</div>
```

### Step by step with `grid-auto-flow: row` (default)

Using a grid with `grid-template-columns: auto auto max-content` and starting with an empty grid with the "cursor" at (1,1), adding elements one at a time.

The first element has `grid-column: span 2;`, so it goes into (1,1) and (2,1) with the "cursor" now at (3,1).
[image: 1]

The next element however has `grid-column: 1`, but the grid is at (3,1) currently, so it **skips** (3,1) and goes to the next row at (1,2) then advances to (2,2).
[image: 2]

The next element has `grid-column: 2`, and that matches where the grid is up to already, so the element goes in (2,2) and the grid moves onto (3,1).
[image: 3]

Next up the 4th element has `grid-column: 3` and `grid-row: span 2`. That matches and the cell below is empty so it takes up (3,2) and (3,3). This leaves a gap at (1,1) however, because the span always goes "forward".
[image: 4]

Now starting the next data item, the grids at (1,3) which matches `grid-column: 1` and (2, 3) is still empty, so the element goes there.
[image: 5]

(3,3) is already taken so is skipped over, but that is OK because the next element is column 1 anyway, then 2 after that, then back onto element 4 which again spans down below, although this time there was something above already anyway.
[image: 6]

### And with `grid-auto-flow: dense`

With the dense value, the grid will try and fill in any gaps, such as the one at (3,1). This makes the layout identical for the first 3 elements (because of the column restrictions), but then when the 4th element wants the so far empty 3rd column, the grid layout moves it to the top of that column, this time leaving no gap. And with no gaps left, the next set of elements repeats this.
[image: 7]

### So general solution

- To be repeatable, each data item / "row", must have elements to fill in all cells, such that each new one starts with a fresh row.
- In order to allow an element to fill in a cell "already passed", use `grid-auto-flow: dense`, otherwise the grid elements need to be in the same order as they will be visually.
- The `order` property doesn't really help much because you cant make it repeat every n items. You would need to make CSS rules up to the total number of elements (not practical for a dynamic list/data set) or possibly use inline `style` attribute.
- Setting `grid-row` to explicit row numbers has the same issue.

With dense any ordering can be used:
[image: 8]
Otherwise the elements need to be in order or cells get skipped while it only advances "forward":
[image: 9]

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to achieve is not possibly with a `grid` display. The only possible way to reorder columns without making use of rows is to utilise [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Using **[`flex-direction: row-reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)** **automatically** re-orders the rows from last to first, and you can even 'overflow' this reversal across rows with **[`flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)**.

It's also possible to **completely** modify the order that the elements appear in, by extending this with the [**`order`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/order) property. In the following example, I've added it to a few **[`:nth-of-type(4n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)** pseduo-selectors. Note that it's specifically **`4n`** because there are four columns per 'row'.

```css
.flex {
  width: 342px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(4n) {
  order: 2;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(4n + 1) {
  order: 1;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(4n + 2) {
  order: 3;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(4n + 3) {
  order: 4;
}

.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.col1 {
  background: #F99;
}

.col2 {
  background: #9F9;
}

.col3 {
  background: #99F;
}

.col4 {
  background: #9FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div>
  <div class="col2">2</div>
  <div class="col3">3</div>
  <div class="col4">4</div>
  
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div>
  <div class="col2">2</div>
  <div class="col3">3</div>
  <div class="col4">4</div>
  
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div>
  <div class="col2">2</div>
  <div class="col3">3</div>
  <div class="col4">4</div>
  
</div>
```

In the above example, all of the `.col3` elements are wrapped first, then all of the `.col2` elements, then all of the `.col4` elements, then all of the `.col1` elements. Feel free to adapt this to suit; all you will need to do is change the `order` values, and the elements that the `order` property is applied to. Keep in mind that `order` can go up to the **total** number of elements; you could specify **all 12** positions manually if you so desired:

```css
.flex {
  width: 342px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: 4;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 2;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  order: 1;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(4) {
  order: 3;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(5) {
  order: 8;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(6) {
  order: 6;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(7) {
  order: 5;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(8) {
  order: 7;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(9) {
  order: 12;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(10) {
  order: 10;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(11) {
  order: 9;
}

.flex > div:nth-of-type(12) {
  order: 11;
}

.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.col1 {
  background: #F99;
}

.col2 {
  background: #9F9;
}

.col3 {
  background: #99F;
}

.col4 {
  background: #9FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div>
  <div class="col2">2</div>
  <div class="col3">3</div>
  <div class="col4">4</div>
  
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div>
  <div class="col2">2</div>
  <div class="col3">3</div>
  <div class="col4">4</div>
  
  <!--"row"-->
  <div class="col1">1</div>
  <div class="col2">2</div>
  <div class="col3">3</div>
  <div class="col4">4</div>
  
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: not really sure what you are trying to show. You put all the same classes together in groups, 3,3,3, 2,2,2, 4,4,4, 1,1,1 rather than like 3,2,4,1, 3,2,4,1,  etc.? The `order` property can be used with grids if that is what you are showing? See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#order-property  "The order property also applies to grid items. It affects their auto-placement and painting order."

Comment: The items can be rearranged into any order you would like using the above method. You can easily show it like `3, 2, 4, 1` on each row if you would prefer, by specifying an `order` for **each** element, up to the total number of elements (see my last paragraph). Is that what you're trying to achieve? If not, what **exactly** are you trying to achieve, and what **exactly** are you struggling with? Also, what are your constraints?

Comment: I've updated my answer to showcase this second example, with all three rows utilising `3, 2, 4, 1` for their order.

Comment: Well, I still wanted the rowspan ideally. but with the original HTML. Anyway, I think I discovered going through the specs for all the properties a solution that works for all cases I can think of. e.g. here is the same order as you made, but I didn't need all that `nth-of-type` stuff, it simply repeats.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvOOZW